# How can you style a section in salesforce community?

Tags: community, lightning-experience, css, community-builder

Is there a good way to target a specific section within a community page?
(Also I am under the assumption that this styling is either done in CSS overrides or the theme of the page, please let me know if I am approaching this wrong)

*Note: I am using the flexible page layout*

For example I am trying to change the styling of a managed component that is used in other sections of the page, but I only want to change the styling within one section not all sections, I also need a margin in that section and a background colour.

If there is documentation that I have missed I would also appreciate a link to it so I can refer to it in the future, thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: have you tried using the design attributes to selectively control the styling ? Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm

Comment: @prabuddhkumar because the components are apart of a managed package I can't edit the component specifically, I'm more hoping for a nice way to target a specific section on the page and style the components within that section

Comment: Right now I'm targeting the nth class to get to the section that I want in css, but this way will fall apart if a new section is ever added...